# How to open a link referencing to a file system

Tags: web-applications, hyperlink

How i will open the following link

```
<a href=file:///blablabla/folder>Open folder</a>
```

It is not opening on clicking the anchor.

I mean to say that if we want to access shared folder. Like from \192.168.10.1\XYZ, then.

Comment: Some clarification would be welcome. What language/environment are you using for your web application?

Comment: I am using ASP.NET 3.5 with C#. I am running the application in Windows XP os with mozilla firefox browser.

Comment: Do you mean to open the folder inside the browser, or to launch an external application, like nautilus or Windows explorer?

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifying an absolute path? For example, the following will work fine in Windows:

```
<a href="file:///C:\MyFolder">Open folder</a>
```

Note also that you missed the quotes around the folder path.

Comment: I am sorry, i mean to say that if we want to access shared folder. Like from \\192.168.10.1\XYZ, then.

Answer (score 0):

The file:

```
<a href=file:///tmp>Open folder</a>
```

works fine for me under Ubuntu 9.10 in Firefox 3.5.5 as does:

```
<a href="file:///tmp">Open folder</a>
```

which is probably better. I suspect you may be having another issue. If you're doing this on a Windows server, you may need the drive letter as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to do this from windows:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>My UNC Opener</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <a href="\\192.168.10.1\XYZ">Testing</a>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Please note that most modern browsers know how to append the `file:///` prefix to something referenced on the filesystem, however, Firefox (Tested with version 3.5.6) requires it.  Thus, your code should look like this for the same example:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>My UNC Opener</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <a href="file:\\\\\192.168.10.1\XYZ">Testing</a>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Yes, thats five (5) backslashes (\) in there.

Hope this helps,

### Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the research & Good point but when i am running this in local machine it is working fine but when i am running it in server it is not working specially for FF 3.5.6. I am developing my application in ASP.NET 3.5 framework.

Comment: and one more thing is, i have given the target as "_blank" for opening it in new tab. The href is correct but on clicking it is not opening in FF but opening in IE.