# Link to file in network working in browser but not in HTML Site

Tags: html, hyperlink, filesystems

I am facing a strange problem right now:

I got a link to a file on a network in the following format:

```
file://///server.com/awesome/route/to/file.wav
```

(I used the 5 Slashes as suggested in this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952489/how-to-open-a-link-referencing-to-a-file-system))

When I copy & paste the link in the browser, it works like a charm.
But when I include the link in my HTML Page with

```
<a href="file://///server.com/awesome/route/to/file.wav">Link</a>
```

the link is not working. There is absolut no reaktion of the browser. He does not even try to access the file.

Tested with:

Chrome and Firefox on Windows 7

Comment: As described in the accepted answer to the duplicate question, linking to file: URIs from websites is forbidden by browser security policies.

Comment: Thank you I didn't stumble over that Thread.